# nginx location regex for multiple paths but invalid

Tags: regex, nginx

```
    location ^~/images/ {
        root /mnt/disha;
    }
    location ^~/pdf/ {
        root /mnt/disha;
    }
    location ^~/contact/ {
        root /mnt/disha;
    }
    location ^~ /excel {
        root /mnt/disha;
    }
```

How can I combine these 4 into 1 location?

I tried this:

```
location ~ ^/(images|pdf|contact|excel)/ {
    root /mnt/disha;
}
```

It worked fine with 4 location, then nginx comes 404 Not Found once combining with 1.

I also tried location ~* ^/(images|pdf|contact|excel).

all methods I tried is invalid, what should I do?

here is my entire server conf:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name erp.xxx.com;
    index index.html;
    location ~ ^/(images|pdf|contact|excel)/ {
        root /mnt/disha;
    }
    location ^~/{
        root /mnt/disha/erp;
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/xxx/xxx.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/xxx/xxx.key;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM- 
    SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```

the 404 request i tested:

```
wget http://erp.xxx.com/excel/export_outbound_stock_20200321150255.xls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^~` modifier causes a matching prefix `location` to take precedence over all regular expression `location` blocks.

The `location ^~ / { ... }` effectively disables any regular expression location.

To change your four prefix `location` blocks into a single regular expression `location` block, you must also remove the `^~` modifier from the final `location` block.

For example:

```
root /mnt/disha/erp;

location / {
}

location ~* ^/(images|pdf|contact|excel)/ {
    root /mnt/disha;
}
```

In fact, the `location /` block can be omitted if it is empty, as the `root` statement can be placed in the `server` block context.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.